# How to model subclasses correctly/efficiently in rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

After a very confusing afternoon looking at single table inheritance, polymorphic associations, etc I'm at a complete loss as to the right way to model a fairly simple problem.

Essentially, I need represent different types of page.  The individual pages types will have a variable set of fields so I'm expecting to store them as different models.  They will share certain bits of data (eg whether they're currently published) and some functionality (eg to generate a static version of the page).  Before looking into how rails handles things, my natural reaction was to think I needed a Page object with everything else subclassing that but it seems that maybe that's not the best thing.  Alternatively it seems that I could use polymorphic association but I'm confused as to how to implement this.

This is my first time using rails for an actual project and although I think I could cobble something together, I'd really appreciate some help with picking the right method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're thinking correctly in my opinion. It's either inheritance or polymorphic models. I think that polymorphic models is the best way to go. You would have a Page model and then a User_Page, Blog_Page or whatever you want. Each of these model will have some attributes that the others do not. Polymorphic is pretty easy to implement. Please take a look here : http://asciicasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association